# How to run an application which import QtQuick2.0 and QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I create qtquick application for the first time. I use QtCreator 3.0, Qt5.2.0, and MSVC2012.
When I wrote the following code, I got  error message. I understand what it says. But I want to use QtQuick 2.0 instead of 1.0 if possible.

Does anyone know how to fix the error?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Sample Code**

[*main.qml*]

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    menuBar:MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: "File"
            MenuItem { text: "Open..." }
            MenuItem { text: "Close" }
        }

        Menu {
            title: "Edit"
            MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
            MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
            MenuItem { text: "Paste" }
        }
    }
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

[*main.cpp*]

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/QtQuickAppTest/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Error Message**

```
QQuickView only supports loading of root objects that derive from QQuickItem. 

If your example is using QML 2, (such as qmlscene) and the .qml file you 
loaded has 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', this error will occur. 

To load files with 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', use the 
QDeclarativeView class in the Qt Quick 1 module.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate Qt Quick Application project with option "Qt Quick Control 1.0" rather then "Qt Quick 2.0". It will generate `QtQuick2ControlsApplicationViewer` class, which do not use `QQuickView` but simply `QQmlComponent`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. it works when I create project with option "Qt Quick Control 1.0". I misunderstand the component set.